# Running a python script within wordpress

Tags: python

I have a WordPress install for a personal blog and I'm gradually porting all of the little web bits I have written over the years to pages on the blog.

One such page is http://www.projecttoomanycooks.co.uk/cgi-bin/memory/majorAnalysis.py which is a simple python script that returns a list of words - I'd like to embedd that behavior within a wordpress page - could someone point me in the right direction for the easyist way of running a spot of python within wordpress?

EDIT - following the wonderful answer below, I have got a lot futher... but unfortunately still not quite there...

I have python that executes on server...

```
projecttoomanycooks server [~/public_html/joereddington/wp-content/plugins]#./hello.py 
Hello World!
```

and it's in the same directory as the activated plugin...

The python code... which has the following code...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print("Hello World!")
```

The php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Joe's python thing.
 * Plugin URI: http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
 * Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
 * Version: The Plugin's Version Number, e.g.: 1.0
 * Author: Name Of The Plugin Author
 * Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
 * License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
 */
/*from http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120259/running-a-python-scri
pt-within-wordpress/120261?noredirect=1#120261  */
add_shortcode( 'python', 'embed_python' );

function embed_python( $attributes )
{
    $data = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'file' => 'hello.py'
        ),
        $attributes
    );
    $handle = popen( __DIR__ . '/' . $data['file'], 'r');
    $read   = fread($handle, 2096);
    pclose($handle);

    return $read;
}
```

Comment: If it's a very simple script, I think I would just rewrite it in PHP as a WordPress plugin/template ;-) But in some cases people use iframes to embed external pages.

Comment: iframe it directly? :]

Comment: Is this just an accident, or is your python code really mixed with PHP?

Comment: I pasted the terminal trace, with the files being displayed by the 'more' command... will tidy up a little...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`popen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) to read **or** write to a Python script (this works with any other language too). If you need interaction (passing variables) use [`proc_open()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

#### A simple example to print *Hello World!* in a WordPress plugin

Create the plugin, register a shortcode:

```php
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/* Plugin Name: Python embedded */

add_shortcode( 'python', 'embed_python' );

function embed_python( $attributes )
{
    $data = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'file' => 'hello.py'
        ],
        $attributes
    );

    $handle = popen( __DIR__ . '/' . $data['file'], 'r' );
    $read = '';

    while ( ! feof( $handle ) )
    {
        $read .= fread( $handle, 2096 );
    }

    pclose( $handle );

    return $read;
}
```

Now you can use that shortcode in the post editor with `[python]` or `[python file="filename.py"]`.

Put the Python scripts you want to use into the same directory as the plugin file. You can also put them into a directory and adjust the path in the shortcode handler.

Now create a complex Python script like this:

```python
print("Hello World!")
```

And that’s all. Use the shortcode, and get this output:

> [image]

Comment: Correct answer omits that first line of the the python script, at least in my case, needs to be #!/usr/bin/env python

Comment: @MikeiLL That depends on the user’s system, so I left it out deliberately.

Comment: basically making a security hole. If you can pipe to python, you can pipe to any other process as well and this can be used to escalate any more trivial exploit.

Comment: @MarkKaplun yes, this is not a good idea. To do this "right" there will have to be command escaping going in, and JavaScript+PHP escaping going on. This is not a good way to develop anything inside WordPress, unless there is a VERY specific reason to do this. "Your -scientists- programmers were so preoccupied with whether or not they could, they didn’t stop to think if they should."

Comment: Hi @MarkKaplun , It might be my lack of understanding of php and wordpress. I do understand that as soon as you can pipe arbitrary commands to python, that then you will be able to exucute aribitrary commands on the host as the user under which the python process runs. But in this example there is only ever a read being done from the pipe, so I do not see how this plugin can be used to actually write to the pipe. Additionally only the people actually being able to modify worpress pages are able to exploit this security hole, so this might be an ok solution for a personal wordpress site.

Comment: @M.D., first you need to enable execution out of PHP, and depending on PHP version and webserver you might be able to do it only as a global setting which means that any PHP script can execute everything on the system. From the phyton side, any script can execute it and exploit whatever security problems it has. This might not be a big thing if only you have control of the server and only vetted code is installed, but even if people do the first 99.99% of wordpress sites don't do the second therefor it is best to be avoided as no one can trust themselfs with following the second all the time

Comment: the right way to communicate between phyton and wordpress is to put a cron on phyton and make it query wordpress for whatever information it might need. This way you keep php side secure. still need to ensure it is phyton that asks for the info but this is a more trivial thing to do. But this kind of async communication will not solve the question as the OP asked.

Answer (score 4):

I followed the example script from the first answer, but was getting no output or errors.

I changed this line:

```
$handle = popen( __DIR__ . '/' . $data['file'], 'r' );
```

to this:

```
$handle = popen( __DIR__ . '/' . $data['file'] . ' 2>&1', 'r' );
```

and then got a "permission denied" message.

On the console, I ran

```
chmod 777 hello.py
```

refreshed the page, and everything worked perfectly.

This may be the issue Joe was seeing above.  I don't have enough rep to make a comment, sorry.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Do not make the permission 777. Just make it executale. `chmod +x filename.py` will do

Comment: Changing everything to 777, is very dangerous. Source: https://superuser.com/questions/1034079/is-it-safe-to-chmod-777-everything

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little script that uses `proc_open` as noted above, to sent one simple text variable to a python script:

```
add_shortcode( 'execute_python', 'execute_python_with_argv' );

function execute_python_with_argv( $attributes ){

$description = array (     
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
    2 => array("pipe", "w")   // stderr
);

$application_system = "python ";
$application_path .= plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
$application_name .= "hello.py";
$separator = " ";

$application = $application_system.$application_path.$application_name.$separator;

$argv1 = '"output to receive back from python script"';
$pipes = array();

$proc = proc_open ( $application.$argv1 , $description , $pipes );

//echo proc_get_status($proc)['pid'];

if (is_resource ( $proc ))
{
    echo "Stdout : " . stream_get_contents ( $pipes [1] ); //Reading stdout buffer
    fclose ( $pipes [1] ); //Closing stdout buffer
    fclose ( $pipes [2] ); //Closing stderr buffer

    $return_value = proc_close($proc);
    echo "<br/>command returned: $return_value<br/>";
}

$application_test = glitch_player_DIR.$application_name;

echo "<br/>Is ".$application_test." executable? ".is_executable($application_test)." ";
echo "readable? ".is_readable($application_test)." ";
echo "writable? ".is_writable($application_test)." ";

} //EOF main/shortcode function
```

Added a few tests as the bottom to see if the python file is `rwx`. I think a better way to send the `argv` would be using fwrite, but it wasn't working for me following [this tutorial](http://seriesofexp.wordpress.com/tag/proc_open/).

Here is the python script I used. As noted in comments above, something like `#!/usr/bin/env python` may be necessary, depending on server.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sys import argv

script, what_he_said = argv

print "This is what you submitted: %s \n \n Isn't that amazing, man? " % what_he_said
```