# Trouble implementing python on WordPress

Tags: plugins, shortcode, python

I followed all the directions in this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120259/running-a-python-script-within-wordpress) and I still cannot get a result to display. I know PHP is doing *something*, because there is no text displayed whatsoever. The result has a header and no body content. When the plugin is disabled, it displays the shortcode as plain text.

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/* Plugin Name: Python embedded */

add_shortcode( 'python', 'embed_python' );

function embed_python( $attributes )
{
    $data = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'file' => 'hello.py'
        ),
        $attributes
    );
    $handle = popen( __DIR__ . '/' . $data['file'], 'r');
    $read   = fread($handle, 2096);
    pclose($handle);

    return $read;
}
```

I uploaded **hello.py** and **Python.php** to the plugins folder and made sure the plugin was properly activated.

In my post editor I have:
    [python file="hello.py"].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. First of all, you have to

> $handle = popen('env python '. **DIR** . '/' . $data['file'], 'r');

More importantly, I had to install [Python 2.7.2 on Bluehost](http://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/python-install)

Comment: You can accept your answer so the question is no longer considered unanswered; click the check mark under the vote arrows on the left.