# Accessing data from Google Cloud Datastore in Wordpress site

Tags: plugins, database, google

I want to access data stored in Google Cloud Datastore (or possibly other Google database option) in my Wordpress site. I have tried to find information about this without much luck. The alternatives I can see at the moment are these:

1. Hosting the Wordpress site on Google App Engine, which I suspect would enable me to access the data on Google Cloud Datastore easier (is this so?).
2. Adding a plugin to my Wordpress site (not hosted at Google) that will enable this. The Google App Engine plugin hasn't worked for me so far though. Is it meant to be used only with Google App Engine hosting? From the plugin description:

> Note: This plugin is designed to be used with Google App Engine only
>   and will not work with any other hosting.

Although Google writes:

> "Google Cloud Platform offers several plugins to integrate WordPress
>   with App Engine, Cloud Storage, and more. These plugins can be
>   installed on any WordPress application, not just ones running on
>   Google Cloud Platform."

3. Using [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120259/running-a-python-script-within-wordpress) method to be able to retreive data from the database using Python scripts.

What have I missed? I would have thought this would be fairly common an issue? Thankful for advice on the best option.

Comment: What do you mean by "access data stored in Google Cloud Datastore"? What type of data? In what context? Have you read [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/activate) for it? If you want to access it you need to develop a PHP application to access the data and do with it what you want. Then you could put this into a WordPress plugin. There's not going to be a plugin, because a generic plugin for accessing a database is useless without any functionality to use it somehow, and there's no such thing as a generic use that a plugin could implement.

Comment: If you're talking about just using Cloud Datastore as your WordPress database, then the answer is that you can't. WordPress uses MySQL for its database, and Google Cloud Datastore is not a MySQL database.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I have been using Python to access data via Linux terminal so far. Therefore I was first looking at a way of including that Python script in the Wordpress website somehow (alternative 3 in my question). But from your first comment  I guess it is better writing PHP code for this. I think this is an answer to my question, thanks! I guess I could either make it a plugin or add the PHP code straight into my website code.

Comment: If you're going to use PHP, take the time to make it a WordPress plugin to reduce the security risks.

Comment: @WebElaine Thanks! I have made a plugin now. I would like to add some Python code though to make stats from the Cloud Datastore data. Are there security risks if I embed a Python script in the plugin? (As stated in a comment to the first answer to this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120259/running-a-python-script-within-wordpress.)

Comment: Yes, anytime you open up WP to other systems you're adding one more place that someone with malicious intent could exploit your site. Better to connect via PHP itself in this case.

Comment: @WebElaine Right, thanks! So it is best to use PHP for connecting to the database. Does this go for doing statistics with the data after collecting it too, or is it just the connecting part that is safer with PHP?

Comment: Whether you're connecting to a database or passing values, passing from one system to another opens up a little crack in your site that can be exploited. Not to say you can't ever use other languages, but sticking to whatever language is native - in this case PHP - is at least somewhat safer.