# Trouble running python script in Wordpress

Tags: plugins

I followed all the directions in this post [Running a python script within wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120259/running-a-python-script-within-wordpress) and I still cannot get a result to display.

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/* Plugin Name: Python embedded */

add_shortcode( 'python', 'embed_python' );

function embed_python( $attributes )
{
$data = shortcode_atts(
    [
        'file' => 'hello.py'
    ],
    $attributes
);

$handle = popen( __DIR__ . '/' . $data['file'], 'r' );
$read = '';

while ( ! feof( $handle ) )
{
    $read .= fread( $handle, 2096 );
}

pclose( $handle );

return $read;
}
```

I uploaded hello.py and Python.php to the plugins folder and made sure the plugin was properly activated.

Comment: there is no line 21 in the code you show us.

Comment: Excuse me i edited the code. I tried a lot of changes and I was confused. I have no error with this code but I cannot get a display. I think that it cannot read the python file