# Point Python path in Wordpress

Tags: plugins

I have tried implementing the steps mentioned in this post: [Previous Post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120259/running-a-python-script-within-wordpress)

However, there is not output. it appears that Python script is not executing at all. Just to mention here that I have worked around with Hosting provider to enable popen, pclose, proc_open, and proc_close.

Here is the code in the wordpress plugin:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/* Plugin Name: gm-python */

add_shortcode( 'python', 'embed_python' );

function embed_python( $attributes )
{
    $data = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'file' => 'hello.py'
        ],
        $attributes
    );


    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET'){

        $handle = popen( __DIR__ . '/' . $data['file'] . '2>&1', 'r' );
        $read = '';

        if($read){

            while (!feof($handle))
            {
                $read.= fread($handle, 2096);
            }
        }
    }
    pclose($handle);

    return $read;
}
```

here is what is in the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print('Hello World')
```

I have installed python outside of the websites as well.
[image]

Can anybody help to find the correct way to configure the path for python execution through wordpress plugin?

Comment: Your `if($read)` evaluates to `false`, because you have set it to an empty string. So the `while` statement isn't executed.

Comment: @fuxia I have modified the code as it is in the original post. however, it is still not executing. I am wondering if I am mentioning the shebang path correctly in the python file. In my case python path is not usr/bin/env python rather it is home/(my main account for hosting)/virtualenv/analysis/3.7/bin python.

Comment: I have been struggling to make the simple hello code work out but no luck untill I added the encoding instruction # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- This instruction in hello.py file worked.

Comment: Weird. That shouldn't affect the script execution. :)