# i want to run python script in wordpress

Tags: python

i have a search algorithm that is in python code. i want to integrate that algorithm on our website which is made up of WordPress PHP. Please tell me the way, how can i integrate the python wordpress php.

Comment: Possible? Maybe. A good idea? Not without significant security checking. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120261/16121 and note the comments.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.