# How connect local python app to wordpress

Tags: localhost, python

I’m new to wordpress. I have a webapp written in matlab and compiled to a python package. I use it in a local server that’s is connected to the interent with a Django project.
I want to move the functionailty to wordpress. I basically need:

1. users choose some options that will be sent to my local machine.
2. users receieve output variables sent by the machine.
3. the wordpress site uses these variables to plot graphs.

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Did you read this: [thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120259/running-a-python-script-within-wordpress)? Might give you some idea how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks, yes I saw it but I thought it's a different problem to me.From the answers it seems like they recommended the OP to create a wordpress plugin. but I still don't understand. for that, do I need to have my wordpress installed on the same machine as my python app? because right now it's on hostgator

Comment: Your Python app needs to offer some kind of REST API that your WordPress plugin can access. Then it doesn't matter in what language it is written. I can write a very rough example, if that doesn't help already. :)

Comment: Oh I see. so it works if wordpress is hosted on a different machine than the app. It would be really great if you give me an example or point me to one. or at least tell me how I search for it. I kinda can'T find the right search terms to describe the problem.