# Run Python Script on WordPress Website

Tags: plugins, python

I am trying to run A python Script as mentioned in the following link..

[Running a python script within wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120259/running-a-python-script-within-wordpress/241681#241681?newreg=fd10decb89534cc8a7d39a634a3773fb)

But I am still getting the message "permission denied".

Comment: Does your script have the 'x' executable permission set for the user your web server is running as? (However it might be better to call the python interpreter explicitly, rather than just running the .py script directly, else you've really written a 'run arbitrary command' shortcode not a python shortcode.)

Comment: yes. it is having permission..

Comment: OK, then you're going to have to work out where the 'permission denied' is coming from then. I don't think you've given us enough information to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This issue of permission denied is resolved.. Permission was already given but I have added 'env python' in the popen function.. Now the code is running as expected..

```
add_shortcode( 'run_test_py', 'test_py' );

function test_py( $attributes )
{
    $data = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'file' => 'test.py'
        ],
        $attributes
    );

    $handle =  popen('env python '. __DIR__ . '/' . $data['file'] . ' 2>&1', 'r' );
    $read = '';

    while ( ! feof( $handle ) )
    {
        $read .= fread( $handle, 2096 );
    }

    pclose( $handle );

    return $read;
}
```

Comment: env python doesn't require the script it's running to have execute permissions, so if that works and the old way doesn't you probably did have the permissions set incorrectly, or set for the wrong user or group.

Comment: previously I have given permission using cmd but that didn't work, then I tried with file explorer via Godaddy & gave the permission from there but still that didn't work. then I added "env python " then it worked.