# Python with wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, errors, testing, python

I am trying to do some experiments with python and wordpress plugins. I would like to have shortcode [python] with some functionalities. I was trying this metod - **[Method i tried](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120259/running-a-python-script-within-wordpress?rq=1)**, but when I do everything by that i got error message - **sh: 1: /www/doc/mywebsitename/www/wp-content/plugins/PythonEmbed/pythonScript.py: not found**

***My PHP code:***

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: PythonWeb
 * Description: Python integration on web
 * Version: 0.0.1
 * Author: mywebsitename
 * Author URI: mywebsitename
 */

add_shortcode( 'python', 'embed_python' );

function embed_python( $attributes )
{
    echo "PHP start!<br>";
    $data = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'file' => 'pythonScript.py'
        ],
        $attributes
    );

    $handle = popen( __DIR__ . '/' . $data['file'] . ' 2>&1', 'r' );
    $read = '';
    
    while ( ! feof( $handle ) )
    {
        $read .= fread( $handle, 2096 );
    }

    pclose( $handle );
    
    return $read;
}
```

***Python test code:***

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Python is running !!!"
```

Can someone help me to run python code in WordPress plugin so i could test some things?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well based on the error message, is the script in that location?

Comment: You'll also need to make sure the web server user has permission to read and execute that script, and that your Python interpreter is /usr/bin/python, although I'd expect a slightly different error message for either of those.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yeah the script is in the same folder as PHP

Comment: @Rup For the first time it wrote not permission then that error message :(